# php script invoking a python script works in the ssh terminal but no output in the browser window

Tags: php, python-3.x, server

The following pieces of code when executed using php -f phptest.php gave the output (server is a GCP virtual instance running Centos7):

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
string(34) "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]"

In the terminal window. On the other hand the same code when run using the server IP and appropriate URL gives:

string(0) ""

Here are the two scripts :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
def foo():    
    x=str([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])  
    return x  
x=foo()  
print(x)
```

and

```
<?php
$command = "python_location pyfile.py"
escapeshellcmd($commmand);
$output = shell_exec($command);
$strout=print_r($output,true);
echo($strout);
var_dump($strout);
?>
```

The server doesn't have a directory /var/log/apache2/error.log. Instead i was able to find /var/log/httpd/error_log which contains the following:

[Sun Jun 16 05:04:34.269345 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 21434] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jun 16 05:04:34.284400 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 21434] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jun 16 05:04:34.284500 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21434] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 16 05:04:34.284505 2019] [core:notice] [pid 21434] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jun 16 05:11:53.245377 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 32206] [client 187.10.191.110:35833] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Jun 16 07:08:12.657568 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 32210] [client 138.99.101.198:49444] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Jun 16 09:09:49.507235 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 32209] [client 170.130.187.26:54699] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Jun 16 09:10:47.289063 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 32207] [client 190.29.16.112:57449] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Jun 16 13:50:02.964126 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 32209] [client 95.141.135.6:34567] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Jun 16 14:27:36.383175 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 32207] [client 139.162.119.197:35716] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

'server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive' leads me to believe that this could possibly be changed through httpd.conf possibly?

Ideally the output in the browser would match the one I get in the ssh terminal

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What kind is the web server? Can you provide an example of the error logging of the web server?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no errors were raised when this was executed. As for the server : its a Centos7 GCP instance

Comment: See Centos7 is the OS of the server I am asking about the web server, like Apache or Ngnix or ...

Comment: the server runs Apache 2.4.

Comment: Since the server is Apache, can you paste here the content of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: added the contents in the question!

Comment: In which directory the above php script is located?

Comment: The php script lies in var/www/html/more_directories/phpcall which also contains the python script being called here (in a python virtualenv)

Comment: Can you check if this script is executed successfully?  
Maybe if you look in `/var/log/httpd/access_log` you will find it there.  I am not sure about the Centos paths

Comment: IP - - [24/Jun/2019:07:25:51 +0000] "GET /location_of_php HTTP/1.1" 200 19 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770100 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your PHP version is not updated and I tried in my pc and it is working fine. Try to update PHP

Comment: My php is up to date according to the machine.